# Understanding Python's Decimal.quantize method

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I am using the following approach to truncate my floating point values to `X` decimal places (12 in my case).

```
Decimal(val).quantize(Decimal(1).scaleb(-12), rounding=ROUND_UP)
```

I don't really care much about whether the value is rounded up or down but when I ran a few tests, with various values, I noticed a discrepancy with one use-case

With the following code, I understand each use case except for `t4`:

```
t1 = Decimal(-0.04).quantize(Decimal(1).scaleb(-2), rounding=ROUND_UP)
print(f"t1: {t1}")
t2 = Decimal(-0.05).quantize(Decimal(1).scaleb(-2), rounding=ROUND_UP)
print(f"t2: {t2}")
t3 = Decimal(-0.22).quantize(Decimal(1).scaleb(-2), rounding=ROUND_UP)
print(f"t3: {t3}")

t4 = Decimal(-0.092314564913).quantize(Decimal(1).scaleb(-12), rounding=ROUND_UP)
print(f"t4: {t4}")
t5 = Decimal(-0.092314564914).quantize(Decimal(1).scaleb(-12), rounding=ROUND_UP)
print(f"t5: {t5}")
t6 = Decimal(-0.09231456491391342377614447500).quantize(Decimal(1).scaleb(-12), rounding=ROUND_UP)
print(f"t5: {t6}")
```

The output is as follows:

```
t1: -0.05
t2: -0.06
t3: -0.23
t4: -0.092314564913
t5: -0.092314564915
t5: -0.092314564914
```

The output values for `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t5`, `t6` made sense to me but can't understand why `t4` outputs `-0.092314564913` and does not round up to `-0.092314564914` like the behavior of `t1` to `t3`.

Comment: Have you checked the result of `Decimal(-0.092314564913)` in a REPL?

Comment: When creating Decimals make sure to use *strings*.  Floating point initializers are inexact. You get quite difference results with, e.g., `Decimal(-.04)` vs. `Decimal('-.04')`.  The former returns `Decimal('-0.040000000000000000832667268468867405317723751068115234375')
`.  `t4 == Decimal('-0.092314564912999996781906020260066725313663482666015625')` which rounds up to what you see.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank You!  That was it, when I switched to using a string, I see expected results.